# How to display Dates on x axis in the graph with DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd     
from pandas_datareader import data as wb            
import numpy as np      
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt         
import matplotlib.dates as dates
assets= ["WMT", "FB"]  
source=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/HarshitGoyal/Downloads/Walmart_FB_2014_2017.csv", index_col="Date")     
source= (source/source.iloc[0])*100      
source.plot(figsize=(10,5))
```

and obtained the following output(Please click on the URL below):

Here, Date is displayed on the graph but not the values. Please help!
P.S.- I am a beginner in Python.

[image: pic]

[Here is the link of the CSV file of the data.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b8c68242gximmhv/AACWhL09-jp4ETdsBUPJDgQHa/CSV/Python%203%20CSV?dl=0&preview=Walmart_FB_2014_2017.csv)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide always a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't have your csv file, so we wouldn't know your data structure.

Comment: @Mr.T **The CSV file has been attached.** Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is your `source.index` is as `str` type. Since your are working with stock prices, i.e. Time Series data, so the better way is to turn the index as `datetime` type, with the parameter: `parse_dates=True`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Walmart_FB_2014_2017.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
>>> dff = df / df.iloc[0]
>>> dff.plot()
```

Also, for simple case plots, Pandas built-in [visualization](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) ability can just work.

[image]

Check the `dtype` difference:

```
>>> source = pd.read_csv('Walmart_FB_2014_2017.csv', index_col='Date')
>>> source.index
Index(['2013-12-31', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-07',
       ...
       '2017-04-03', '2017-04-04', '2017-04-05', '2017-04-06', '2017-04-07'],
      dtype='object', name='Date', length=824)
>>> # Note the differences.
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Walmart_FB_2014_2017.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2013-12-31', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-06',
               ...
               '2017-04-04', '2017-04-05', '2017-04-06', '2017-04-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=824, freq=None)
```

Comment: @YaOzl  Well. That helped a lot. Thank you so much. Also, can you please guide me from where I should learn Python libraries such as pandas in greater depth.

Comment: @HarshitGoyal Personally, I think the best way to learn Pandas is just read through it's **[great docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)**, take a look at *Table Of Contents* and read anything you interested.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for the advice. Done.

Comment: @YaOzl Thank you so much! Yeah. I upvoted it but it isn't showing up as my reputation points are less than 15.

Comment: @Mr.T Ah. I see. Got it! Thanks!